# IOException loading PNG image

Tags: java-me

---

I am currently working on a school J2ME project using Canvas and I am trying to get the Ping Pong ball app ready for tomorrow's exam, but when loading a PNG image with Image.createImage(url) I get an IOException (the image is in the right src file and it's 32x32 pixels)

This is my code:

```
public class BallGame extends GameCanvas implements Runnable {

private Image ballImg;

private Sprite ballSprite;
private String url="/ball.PNG";
private int ballX = getWidth() / 2;
private int ballY = getHeight() / 2;

public BallGame() {
    super(false);
}

public void run() {

    while (true) {
        try {
            updateScreen(getGraphics());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

public void start() {
    try {
        ballImg = Image.createImage(url);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("*********");
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("********************");
    }

    ballSprite = new Sprite(ballImg, 32, 32);
    ballSprite.setRefPixelPosition(16, 16);
    ballSprite.setPosition(ballX, ballY);

    Thread runner = new Thread(this);
    runner.start();

}

public void Createbackground(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(0x000000);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
}

public void updateScreen(Graphics graphics) {
    Createbackground(graphics);
    ballSprite.setRefPixelPosition(ballX, ballY);
    ballSprite.paint(graphics);
    flushGraphics();

}

public void moveBall() {

}}
```

Comment: omg this title worked

Comment: It might be easier to get help if you paste the stackTrace you get. Also, if you use the correct title for the question!

Comment: i spent easily 30 min entering titles and they dont get accpeted.

Comment: @MohamedAssilMekki I have my doubts.

Comment: Cleaned up grammar, spelling and capitalization, removed verbiage and added a decent title

Comment: Remember "ball.PNG" is not the same as "ball.png". So be absolutely sure that your actual filename is the same as the filename you're trying to load.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you have a wrong path or some problems with the ownership of the file. Check if some other program is editing it.

Have you tried adding a full absolute path? 
Also have you tried using the "ball.png" image inside the same folder without folder paths like:

```
private String url="ball.PNG";
```

If that works it's definitely a path problem.

In my J2ME device version when I open a file my path starts like this:

```
String path_start="file:///a:/";
```